# How to use a switch to assign value to a selected item from a JComboBox

Tags: java, switch-statement

Here is my problem:

In our term there are two java courses. we have been learning about GUI elements.  In our latest assignment, we have to register an attendees name. the name will be taken from  text box, and a combo box in which they have option to attend as a business person ($895), student ($495), or complimentary ($0).

My question is this:

**we are directed to use a switch statement to determine the the registration fee.**  How can I do this?

Comment: do you have to do the stuff in Swing or in JSP/HTML/Javascript ?

Comment: @Hovercraft: if you are using swing then answer given by [Hovercraft](http://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) seems to be correct. you should try it.

Comment: And I will be.  Thanks a lot for the comments and help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use a `JButton` and its `ActionListener` code to "accept" the input.  In the `actionPerformed()` method you check the JComboBox's selected index (*you could check the selected item, but that won't work for your switch statement*) and test the returned `int` in your switch block.  You can get the selected index by calling `getSelectedIndex()` (but of course!) on the `JComboBox`.  I assume that you're clear on how to use a switch statement, correct?

In pseudocode

```
begin actionPerformed method
  get selected index from combobox
  do switch on selected index
     case 0: set registration fee to first value, break
     case 1: set registration fee to second value, break
     case 2: set registration fee to third value, break
     default -- something's wrong. ;)
  end of switch
end of action performed
```

Comment: I was trying to get the index out of the Box by using the getSelectedIndex(), but I must be doing something wrong, as I get an 'unreachable statement' error.  I am comfortable with switches, but this is the first assignment using actionPerformed, so I am a little confused as to what goes where.  In our previous asign. we started using action events, but I'm just starting in on the action Performed business.

Comment: If you've reached an unreachable statement, then you've got an error in your code, perhaps code after a return statement or code after a non-ending loop, and you'll need to debug this or post your code.

Comment: In the assignment, we have to write a separate handler class (ActionListener, ItemListener, and FocusListener), and an actionperformed method.  It is not to be written in the class I am working on now.  The class I am working on now is called 'RegPanel', and the handler will be called  'ConferenceHandler'.  In the class I am working on now, how do you reference the (future) actionperformed method?  Also, here is a bit of rough code I have done for the switch:

Comment: public double getRegCost()
   {
      int selection = regBox.getSelectedIndex();
      switch (selection)
         {
            case 1: selection = 1;
                    return BUSINESS;
                    break;
            case 2: selection = 2;
                    return STUDENT;
                    break;
            case 3: selection = 3;
                    return COMP;
                    break;                    where BUSINESS, STUDENT, and COMP are named constants containing the costs.

Comment: @unit: in your code `break` statement is unreachable code as you `return` from method before `break`.

Comment: oh crap.  What a dummy.  Thank you.  Apparently sometimes when you learn something new, you forget something old.

Comment: Yep code after a return statement -- knew it.  Also, shouldn't your case begin with 0, not 1?

Comment: @Hovercraft, @unit: yeah hovercraft is right you should begin your case with `0` cause in `JComboBox` index starts with `0`.

Comment: Ooooh..I actually thought of that....but the first case at [0] in my array is actually a title for the textbox (Please select a type).  And I don't want them to choose that.  That is, 'Please select a type' is what it says as a title in the textbox, then you pull down to select from index numbers 1-3.

Comment: @unit: if thats the case then you are right in starting from case 1. But i advise you use `JLabel` for title. But also its okay if go like this nothing to worry about it.

Comment: Actually, we are instructed to do it this way.  But it's good to know that in the real world we would just give it a label.